# Demonstrating pointwise convergence

Tags: real-analysis, functions, convergence-divergence, pointwise-convergence

I can't seem to find a way to demonstrate that the sequence of functions $$f_n(x)=
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
4n^2x\qquad if \qquad 0\le x\le \frac1{2n} \\ 
-4n^2x+4n\qquad if \qquad \frac1{2n}\lt x\lt \frac1{n} \\ 
0\qquad if \qquad \frac1{n}\le x\le 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$ converges pointwise. I know that I need to find $f(x)$ but I don't know how exactly. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

First note that $f_n(0)=0$ for all $n$. And if $0<x\leq 1$ then there is some positive integer $N$ such that $\frac{1}{N}\leq x$, so $f_n(x)=0$ for $n\geq 0$. Therefore the pointwise limit is $0$.

In general, it can be helpful to sketch the graphs of the first few $f_n$. In this case the portion of the graph where $f_n$ is non-zero is a triangle which becomes increasingly tall and thin as $n$ increases.

Comment: You can also see that, since the third condition implies $f_n(x)\to 0$ for  each $x>0,$ and since the first condition implies $f_n(0)=0$ for all $n,$  that the second condition is irrelevant to the Q of point-wise convergence.

Comment: True, though I suspect that this is part of a larger problem, since the integral of each $f_n$ is $1$.

Comment: Interesting point.................

Comment: Thank you so much! I think I got it now, the graphic helped.